# EF Core additional foreign key field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have simplified my EF model. The code below gives a desired result. However, one particular field declaration looks weird to me.
I try adding an Entity **E1** a Field of type Entity **E2**.

```
[Table(Constants.Tables.Entities.Name, Schema = Constants.Tables.Entities.Schema)]
public class Entity
{
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }

    public Guid ComponentId { get; set; }     // Parent Component reference
    public Component? Component { get; set; } // Reference instance

    public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; } = new List<Field>();
// ?
    [NotMapped] internal Field DummyField { get; set; }  // Dummy link???
// ?
    internal static void Build(EntityTypeBuilder<Entity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.EntityId);
        builder.Property(p => p.EntityId).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedNever();
        builder.HasMany(e => e.Fields).WithOne(e => e.Entity).IsRequired().HasForeignKey(f => f.EntityId);
    }
}

[Table(Constants.Tables.Fields.Name, Schema = Constants.Tables.Fields.Schema)]
public class Field
{
    public Guid FieldId { get; set; }

    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }     // Parent Entity this field belongs to
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }     // Parent Entity instance

    public Guid FieldTypeId { get; set; }  // Actual Entity reference
    public Entity FieldType { get; set; }  //

    internal static void Build(EntityTypeBuilder<Field> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(f => f.FieldId);

        builder.HasOne(p => p.FieldType)     // Is this the only way describe
               .WithOne(p => p.DummyField)   // using dummy field???
               .HasForeignKey<Field>(p => p.FieldTypeId);

        builder.Property(p => p.EntityId).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedNever();
        builder.Property(p => p.FieldTypeId).IsRequired();        
    }
}

// Let's re-create database and seed some data:

    [Test]
    public void Build_simple_component()
    {
        using var metadataContext = new MetadataContext(dbOptions);

        var entity1 = new Entity
        {
            EntityId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            EntityName = "E1",
        };
        var entity2 = new Entity
        {
            EntityId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            EntityName = "E2",
        };
        component.Entities.Add(entity1);
        component.Entities.Add(entity2);
        var field1 = new Field
        {
            FieldId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "F1",
            FieldTypeId = entity1.EntityId,  // E1 reference
        };
        entity2.Fields.Add(field1);

        metadataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

So the `Field` table row is correct:

```
FieldId        Name  EntityId               FieldTypeId
<random_guid>  F1    <parent_entity_E2_id>  <entity_E1_id>
```

Is there any other way to describe `Field.FieldTypeId` with a constraint *without* introducing a 'hidden' `Entity.DummyField` property?

Comment: just `.WithOne()`?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it works! Now I better surf for even more docs as the most I found was copy-paste from the same old book with just a few examples. Thanks!